# Unable to automatically step into server. Connecting to server machine failed. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm trying to connect to a remote web service but keep getting this error. It all of a sudden started happening after working correctly for months. Could this be an authentication issue? Please help!

[image: error]